# Thread problem and communication problem with OpenCV and Gtk in python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, gtk

I want to capture the webcam in a thread or a process with opencv and I want to know if the camera is displaying and I also want to tell the thread to stop.
The webcam code:

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self, debug=0,log_file="",started_queue=None):
        self.logger = self.init_log(debug,log_file)
        self.stopped=False
        self.saving=0
        if started_queue!=None:
            self.started=started_queue
        else:
            self.started=None
        self.font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 

    def start(self,source=0,video_file_name="",video_overlay="",window_title=""):
        #t1=threading.Thread(target=self.display,args=(source,video_file_name,video_overlay,window_title)).start()
        t1=multiprocessing.Process(target=self.display,args=(source,video_file_name,video_overlay,window_title)).start()
                         
    def display(self,source,video_file_name,video_overlay,window_title):
        self.cam= cv2.VideoCapture(source)
        reponse, frame = self.cam.read()
        video_overlay= unidecode.unidecode(video_overlay)
        window_title= unidecode.unidecode(window_title)
        fps=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
        width  = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)        
        height = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
#        if self.started!=None:
#            self.started.put(True)
        if len(video_file_name)>0:
            self.saving=1
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("m","p","4","v")           
            self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file_name, fourcc,fps,(int(width),int(height)))
        reponse=1
        while not self.stopped:
            if not reponse:
                self.stop()
            else:
                reponse, frame = self.cam.read()
                text= datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                text=text+" "+video_overlay     
                frame=cv2.putText(frame,text,(2,20),self.font, 0.5, (255,255,255),1)
                try:
                    if reponse:
                        self.started=True                        
                        cv2.imshow(window_title, frame)
                        if self.saving==1:
                            self.out.write(frame)
                except Exception:
                    pass
                if cv2.waitKey(1)==27 and video_file_name=="":
                    self.stop()
```

When I launch the code in thread. I have no output and the following error:
Gdk-Message: 11:31:13.564: main2.py: Fatal IO error 2 (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type) on X server :0.
When I launch the code with multiprocessing.Process.I have no output and the following error:
main2.py: Fatal IO error 0 (Succès) on X server :0.
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c :260 : poll_for_event:  l'assertion « !xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost » a échoué.
Fatal Python error: Aborted

and if I use idle_add

```
GLib.idle_add(self.camera.display,int(id_webcam),tmp_video_file_name,self.video_overlay_text_entry.get_text(),"Test webcam, appuyez sur échap pour arrêter")
```

It work but I can't find a way to know if the window is displayed. It doesn't work with queue.put and queue.get. And I need a way to speak with the process to tell him to stop when I need to.

If someone have an idea....

Thanks

Comment: Why is there so much questions involving video and opening webcam camera in thread in the past hour? Are you guys all in the same class or something??

Comment: No, I'm alone. I don't work with nobody

Comment: @nathancy I was beginning to have the same feeling